# VS code can't execute Hello World program (Error)

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python on Visual Studio Code, I was about to write my first Hello world program but it gives me this error:

```
print("Hello", end=" ")
print("World!")

print("Hello", end=" ")
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me, thanks for the help!

I'm on a MacBook Pro M1 Max

Comment: bro the it works, is this the full code? this doesn't get an error on my pc

Comment: Yea, I know it works, but on my VScode it's not working, maybe because I'm on Mac? idk

Comment: Yea it works, actually running the code from terminal (not the vs code terminal) it works, so it's a Visual Studio problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using python **2.x version**. `end=` only works for python **3.x**

Comment: Actually, I tried running the "python3" command and it tells me that python 3.8.9 is installed

Comment: Do you have the python extension installed?

Comment: Yea, I also tried running the code on my windows 11 Virtual machine and it runs without problems so it's surely a Mac problem.

Comment: its not just os problems, it could depend on what interpreter you have as choice in vscode

Comment: Alright, tried editing the interpreter by pressing F1, typing Select interpreter and the only choice I have is Python3.9.9 64 Bit (The path is /usr/bin/python3)

Comment: Does other code work normally?

Comment: I tried writing a code like for x in range () and it's working properly, tried, with this one and not working

Comment: I just tried running the code from terminal with the python3 command and it's working, probably it's just a VScode problem